# Как сделать что бы iframe не грузился сразу?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть три таба в каждом будет ифрейм и надо что бы при нажатии они прогружались а не сразу при входе на сайт
Возможно ли это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, возможно. Просто когда Вам надо (через задержку или по какому-то событию) присваиваете ифрейму нужный адрес:

```
frames[0].location.href=url;
```

Comment: Некоторые браузеры могут блокировать такие манипуляции с iframe, лучше по таймауту или экшену добавляйте его в DOM  в необходимое место

Comment: как это сделать?)

Comment: Если вы используете jQuery, то `$('#TARGET_CONTAINER').html('<iframe src="FRAME_URL"></iframe>')`, если нет то `var frame = document.createElement("iframe"); frame.src = "FRAME_URL"` и вставляйте туда, куда нужно